# Dynamic Data Display doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xml-namespaces

I have installed this library to my project and I don't know, but I can't create something with this in my XAML.. I write

```
<d3:
```

It looks like i don't have this library installed.. Have blue underline and error:

> `Error    2   The type 'd3:Chart' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.    D:\C# Visual Studio\GeneratorWPF\GeneratorWPF\MainWindow.xaml   13  10  GeneratorWPF`

@Edit 
its my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="GeneratorWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d3="clr-namespace:DynamicDataDisplay.Markers;assembly=DynamicDataDisplay.Markers"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Generator" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

I've added namespace (i think) but doesn't work Chart

Comment: Please provide some more information. How do you declare d3 namespace? What do you mean under "installed this library to my project", which library causes problem, etc.

Comment: Has you a reference to that assembly in the project file? Is it really exist a type called DynamicDataDisplay.Markers.Chart (check in the Object Browser)?

Comment: What exactly library do you refer? Please give link to DynamicDataDisplay you downloaded

Comment: I downloaded this from NuGet.. Really i don't know where is that reference

Comment: Please, give us the link to package page on nuget site. Or just give the precise package name.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicDataDisplayWpf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of three things is wrong

1. Chart is not in the DynamicDataDisplay.Markers namespace. Check the class and make sure that it is.
2. The DynamicDataDisplay assembly name is not "DynamicDataDisplay.Markers". To check the assembly name, right click the DynamicDataDisplay project and click properties. On the Application tab there should be an assembly name.
3. You don't have the correct reference to the assembly in your project. Look in your project in the solution explorer, expand references, and make sure that the DynamicDataDisplay assembly is listed there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Chart" class under the DynamicDataDisplay.Markers namespace in the recent version of the library you mentioned (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicDataDisplayWpf/).

But there are other *Chart classes, including BarChart and PieChart in that namespace. Maybe you should pick the one?